# How to Calculate Time Remaining - Based on estimated time x rows avaiable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, time

For security reasons, we're using a front end application, where we're uploading a txt file, deleting 2500 records from a SQL database.

I'm using *SQL Server 2008 Mgt Studio* to query the progress of that delete. But this just shows me how many rows I have left, not how much time is left.

How can I add into my query?

A calculation of the estimate *'in minutes'*, remaining on a record deletes?

While there is no fixed amount of time it takes to complete, its been averaging 1.5min to delete each record.

I figured simple math (*2500 x 1.5min = est time remaining*), I just don't know how to write into the query as a new column. Here is where my query is at now:

```
SELECT COUNT (UNITS) AS Orders_Remaining
FROM ORDERS
WHERE UNITS BETWEEN '0001' and '2500'
```

Comment: 1.5min per record ? *really ?*

Comment: Lol yeah, well its a database over in the Asia Pacific. Since we're connecting remotely from North America, there is a bit of latency with just about everything. And to make things more delayed, we only have RO access in the DB. Where as  the front end application we have RW with a different account. Otherwise we'd just do all this from the DB level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
SELECT COUNT (UNITS) AS Orders_Remaining, COUNT(UNITS) * 1.5 AS Minutes_Remaining
FROM ORDERS
WHERE UNITS BETWEEN '0001' and '2500'
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks Hogan. Yeah I have to hand this task over to some of our 2nd shift team members, and wanted to be able to provide them an estimate when its done. This makes that task, that much easier.